# What options are there for formatting text emails in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm hoping that there are some more options for formatting simple emails formatted as text (not HTML) when using a mailer in a Rails app.

By trial and error, I've found that this markup works in the mailer view (i.e. example_mailer_view.text.erb):

```
This will be regular text.

==
This text will be formatted in the large, standard HTML Header1 format.
==

 The space at the left side of this line will cause it to be smaller text.

>The bracket on the left side of this line will cause it to be indented once.

>>This text is indented twice.

>>This text is indented three times.

_Italicized text_

*This text will be bold.*

Multiple returns...


...between these two lines get compressed into just one blank row.
```

Is there full documentation of all markup options?  Do you know of other markup options that are not listed here?  It would be great to have heading2, heading3, etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple text emails are, by definition, simple text. They cannot be formatted. There is no bold simple tyext, nor large simple text, nor italicised simple text. If you see them so, it is because your mail agent is choosing to interpret your plain text emails as if they were written in Markdown; but know that users with other user agents will most likely not see them so. The only way to get rich text emails (i.e. formatted emails) in every email agent (apart from text-only agents such as mutt) is to use an HTML body.